# Javascript textarea onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to make a text area in javascript that by default displays three random three digit numbers and has an onclick highlight all property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery, assuming your text area has id txtArea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   var dig1 = Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 899);
   var dig2 = Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 899);
   var dig3 = Math.floor(100 + Math.random() * 899);
  $('#txtArea').val(dig1 + ' ' + dig2 + ' ' + dig3);

  $('#txtArea').unbind('click').click(function() {
     $(this).select();
  });
});
```

Comment: I got that to work. But how do I display a triplicate of numbers?